# Estruturação da classe Router em PHP com MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Uma url amigável do tipo:

```
www.meusite.com.br/controlador/metodo/argumentos
```

É tratada em minha classe **Request**, onde "explodo" a `url`, separando-a em segmentos, que são respectivamente, `$controller`, `$action` e `$args`, que serão retornados à minha classe **Route**, onde é feito o "roteamento" da aplicação. Até aí Ok.

## Problema

O problema se dá ao simples fato de adicionar um subdiretório. (Então me complico todo, pois sou iniciante em aplicações PHP com MVC, principalmente nos conceitos das classes `Route` e `Request`).

### Estrutura de diretórios

[image: Hierarquia de diretórios da aplicação]

O que está "pegando", é que, da maneira que descrevi o processo no primeiro parágrafo, a aplicação funcionará perfeitamente sem os subdiretórios `Usr` e `Adm`, tendo somente a seguinte hierarquia.

[image: Hierarquia de diretórios da aplicação, eliminando os subdiretórios Usr e Adm]

Pois todo o processo está de acordo com a **Router** e a **Request**.

### Class Router

```
class Router
{
    public static function run(Request $request)
    {
        $controller= $request->getController();
        $action= $request->getAction();
        $args = (array) $request->getArgs();
        $controller = 'Application\Controller\\' . ucfirst($controller);
        $controller = new $controller();
        if (!is_callable(array($controller, $action))) {
            // Algum comando.
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($controller, $action), $args);
    }
    // Mais métodos
```

}

A código acima é responsável pela inclusão dos `Controllers` e pelo chamado aos métodos baseado no que foi retornado pela `Request`. (esta não tem muito código, então colocarei somente o trecho que trata a `url`)

### Request

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (!isset($_GET["url"])) return false;

    $segments = explode("/", $_GET["url"]);
    $this->controller = ($controller = array_shift($segments)) ? $controller : "index";
    $this->action = ($action = array_shift($segments)) ? $action : "main";
    $this->args = (is_array($segments[0])) ? $segments : array();
}
```

## Pergunta

Gostaria de saber, quais alterações devo fazer em ambos os códigos, para que uma chamada à um controlador, em algum dos subdiretórios, possa ser feita com sucesso através do seguinte formato de `url`

```
www.meusite.com.br/nome_do_subdiretorio/controlador/metodo/argumentos
```

Peço desculpas pelo tamanho que ficou a pergunta, mas tentei deixá-la completa rsrs

## Update

### Controller Index

> Exemplificando com este controlador, pois seria o padrão, caso a `url` viesse da seguinte forma: `www.meusite.com.br/nome_do_subdominio/`

```
namespace Application\Adm\Controller;

use MamutePost\Controller;

class Index extends Controller
{
    // ... Métodos
}
```

> MamutePost é uma pasta dentro de Vendor onde coloquei meu "mini-framework", que desenvolvi para trabalhar com o MVC.

Comment: lembro das dores de cabeça que passei quando tentei desenvolver minha própria solução de rota, até o momento em que comecei a trabalhar com o symfony então grande parte dos meus problemas acabaram, não estou querendo fazer divulgação mas se quiser saber mais a respeito fica o meu conselho. Certa vez fiz um trabalho onde o cliente se queixou do synfony ser muito grande para algo respectivamente simples, a vantagem é que ele permite a instalação dos componentes em separado. Segue a referência para o componente de rotas http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html

Comment: @kabstergo Obrigado pelo comentário e realmente creio que tanto o symfony, ou algum outro framework trate muito bem a questão das rotas, inclusive darei uma olhada sim no link, mas por enquanto estou à procura de uma solução sem utilizar framework. rs

Comment: sem problemas, poderia postar o código de um controlador? mas especificamente me refiro ao `namespace` dele, considerando o primeiro exemplo que você deu acredito que seu controlador estaria localizado no namespace `Application\Controller\Nome` já no segundo caso com as subpastas o namespace alterou para `Application\Pasta\Controller\Nome`?

Comment: @kabstergo Irei atualizar :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem inicialmente eu alteraria sua classe `Request` pois assim como ela está programada torna o mecanismo de identificação das rotas muito estático para apenas essa situação. Observe como a simples classe abaixo possibilita a identificação de rotas genéricas segundo uma expressão regular.

```
class Router {

  private static $routes = array();

  private function __construct() {}
  private function __clone() {}

  public static function route($pattern, $callback) {
    $pattern = '/^' . str_replace('/', '\/', $pattern) . '$/';
    self::$routes[$pattern] = $callback;
  }

  public static function execute($url) {
    foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $callback) {
      if (preg_match($pattern, $url, $params)) {
        array_shift($params);
        return call_user_func_array($callback, array_values($params));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

dessa forma você registra as rotas da sua aplicação e utiliza a função de callback para efetuar a chamada ao devido controlador:

```
//registro da rota http://www.meusite.com.br/index/main
Router::route('http://www.meusite.com.br/index/main', function(){
  print "Application\Index\Main" . "<br/>";
});

//registro da rota http://www.meusite.com.br/nome_do_subdiretorio/controlador/metodo/argumentos
Router::route('http://www.meusite.com.br/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)', function($folder, $controller, $action, $args){
  print "Application\\" . $folder . "\\" . $controller . "<br/>";
});
```

sendo assim o seu `requester` ficaria encarregado de apenas efetuar a chamada a classe de rotas passando a url em questão:

```
Router::execute("http://www.meusite.com.br/index/main");
Router::execute("http://www.meusite.com.br/nome_do_subdiretorio/controlador/metodo/argumentos");
```

uma abordagem limpa, simples e eficiente para um sistema de rotas básico
créditos: http://upshots.org/php/php-seriously-simple-router

Comment: irei testar esta solução.

Comment: Obrigado, funcional o script, agora implementarei algumas funcionalidades e colocarei em meu sistema.

Comment: @ThomersonRoncally legal e boa sorte em seus projetos.

Comment: Interessante, onde eu deixaria as rotas? no index? isso que não entendi.